Coercivity of a bilinear form with weight function on $L_\infty(\Omega)$
For $0 \neq w\in L_\infty(\Omega)$, let that we have a bilinear form $\alpha(w;\cdot,\cdot)\,H^1_0(\Omega)\times H^1_0(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}^2,\;\Omega$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2,$ bounded, convex.
The bilinear for is defined as: For all $v,\,z\in H^1_0(\Omega),$
$$
\alpha(w;v,z) = \int_\Omega w\nabla v\cdot \nabla z\,dx,\;\;w\in L_\infty(\Omega). 
$$
Is it sufficient that $w\in L_\infty(\Omega)$ such that the bilinear for be coercive, i.e., exist $a>0$ such that $\alpha(w;v,v) \geq a\|\nabla v\|_{L_2(\Omega)}^2,\;\;w\in L_\infty(\Omega)$ ?

No, of course not. Take $w=0$...

If furthermore $w\neq 0$?

@math_lover Still no, in the form you wrote down I can just choose a $w$ that’s everywhere negative. Then obviously the inequality can’t hold. If you in addition insist that your function is non-negative, then choose $w$ to be only zero on a subset, or say $w$ converges to $0$ at a point. Then you can show in both cases no such $a > 0$ can exist. The condition you wrote down can only be satisfied if $w$ is bounded below, i.e., there exists $a > 0$ s.t. $w \geq a$ a.e. (And you can show that is actually the equivalent condition, with the same $a$ as in your condition.)

If you change $\geq$ to $\leq$ in your condition, then it’s equivalent to $w$ being bounded above, so that would actually follow from $w \in L^\infty(\Omega)$. But that’s not the condition you wrote down.

I think you need $w \geq a > 0$ a.e. for coercivity and your inner product defining an equivalent norm to the "original" Sobolev norm.
